# Unicode character enconding

Tags: unicode

I have a jsp page which takes up first name and last name in chinese language. I am using the struts framework. 
I need to pass the first name and last name from the JSP to servlet in terms of unicode characters.

I am doing the following changes:

**JSP Changes:**

1) `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`

2) `meta content="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` in the header,

The filter which is called before the action servlet, I have used the following code:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

response.setContentType("UTF-8");
```

This did not work, the unicode characters which are passed are incorrect, or something not readable.

Considering the `MVC` framework already creates the request object by the time it reaches the filter,

I modified the `JSP` to include the following lines of code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

< fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8" />

< fmt:setLocale value="zh_CN"/>
```

None of the above changes have worked. Please help me to get the correct unicode characters in the action class.

IS there any modification i need to make in the config files.

Comment: Where are the Unicode characters “passed” that is going wrong? If you are talking about query parameters in the URL then that is not affected by `setCharacterEncoding()` and can only be changed in container-specific config.

Comment: Hi, No I am not passing the query parameters in the URL. It is being passed as part of post request. Can you please let me know what needs to be done so that the unicode characters are passed correctly.

Comment: `setCharacterEncoding` will work on POST request bodies, but only if no other component has called `getReader` or `getParameter` on the request before you call it. Once you call either of them the body is decoded and you can no longer change the encoding. If you have a framework (what framework?) reading parameters before hand, perhaps there is a way to configure the framework to use UTF-8, or to get in before it.

Comment: I am using struts framework. I am not aware how to configure the struts framework to use UTF-8. Currently in my web.xml file, I have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Also the server us weblogic server, and I have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in weblogic.xml. Can you let me know what else needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the Bundle basename.

```
<fmt:setBundle basename = "[base_file_name_of_language_file]"/>
```

where [base_file_name_of_language_file] is equal to whatever name you set your language properties file name to be.

For example, the "MyLanguageFileName" in this file name :

```
MyLanguageFileName_zh_CN.properties
```